# Calculate dynamic height with CSS

Tags: sass

I have a container and an element withing it.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="myEm">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to assign width and hight to that element. It should be a square. I can calculate the width relative to the parent container, but how do I pass the same value to the height:

```
#container .myEm {
   width: calc(100% - 20px);
   height: ???
}
```

Comment: Found this page -- pretty amazing: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make the `myEm` resize using padding bottom (or top) to maintain its aspect ratio. This makes `myEm` strictly a sizing element and you'll need an element inside that will size to itself. Here's what I mean for example:

`myEm` becomes:

```
.myEm {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Then you need an element inside with the actual content:

```
.myEm-inner {
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dgmyxs9v/1/

Comment: This works, unfortunately I cannot add nesting containers. I was thinking if there was a way perhaps to set a variable equal to the width and then use it in height as well.

Comment: Hmm, maybe but I can't think of it. You can place content directly in `myEm` but you lose a lot of flexibility if you want to center text or do overflow properly as such https://jsfiddle.net/za0qv8f7/

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself the wrapping div by using pseudo elements.

This solution will create the same effect – but also make the div stretch to fit content – should it become too large to be contained by the square.

```css
/* sane box-sizing */
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/* box styling */
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 150px;
}

/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-
   This is the aspect ratio part 
   ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––- */ 
.box::before {
  /* aspect ratio keeper – 100% = square */
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}




/* second box */
.box:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: olive; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita labore iusto vero perspiciatis ex fuga natus cum molestiae ut, dolor facere maxime voluptatem nesciunt nihil repellendus culpa eligendi laudantium velit.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h2>Will stretch to content</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita labore iusto vero perspiciatis ex fuga natus cum molestiae ut, dolor facere maxime voluptatem nesciunt nihil repellendus culpa eligendi laudantium velit. Expedita labore iusto vero perspiciatis ex fuga natus cum molestiae ut, dolor.</p>
</div>
```